# Telerik Sitefinity Password Hash function

Tags: c#, hash, passwords, sha1, sitefinity

I have a table with login credentials for a Telerik Sitefinity system. I want to use the same login credentials, but with a different application that doesn't have Sitefinity libraries. I'm struggling with the password encoding, which is set to Hash (Default is SHA1 algorithm).

I tried using the following code to encode passwords, but it doesn't match up with what Sitefinity generated.

```
public string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt); 
    byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
    byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

EXAMPLE:

PASSWORD: password111

SALT: 94EBE09530D9F5FAE3D002A4BF262D2F (as saved in the SF user table)

Hash with function above: 8IjcFO4ad8BdkD40NJcgD0iGloU=

Hash in table generated by SF:A24GuU8OasJ2bicvT/E4ZiKfAT8=

I have searched online if SF generates the encoded password differently, but can't find any results. How can I use the login credentials created by SF without SF libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You right, Sitefinity is using SHA1 algorithm, but you need to use additional ValidationKey from configuration settings.

Here the working example of code for you:

```
private static bool CheckValidPassword(string password)
{
    //from sf_users column [salt]
    var userSalt = "420540B274162AA093FDAC86894F3172";

    //from sf_users column [passwd]
    var userPassword = "a99j8I0em8DOP1IAJO/O7umQ+H0=";

    //from App_Data\Sitefinity\Configuration\SecurityConfig.config attribute "validationKey"
    var validationKey = "862391D1B281951D5D92837F4DB9714E0A5630F96483FF39E4307AE733424C557354AE85FF1C00D73AEB48DF3421DD159F6BFA165FF8E812341611BDE60E0D4A";

    return userPassword == ComputeHash(password + userSalt, validationKey);
}

internal static string ComputeHash(string data, string key)
{
    byte[] hashKey = HexToBytes(key);
    HMACSHA1 hmacshA1 = new HMACSHA1();
    hmacshA1.Key = hashKey;
    var hash = hmacshA1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}

public static byte[] HexToBytes(string hexString)
{
    byte[] numArray = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
    for (int index = 0; index < numArray.Length; ++index)
        numArray[index] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(index * 2, 2), 16);
    return numArray;
}
```

Comment: it works! thanks so much. Where did you find this out? I couldn't find any information on how SF do their hashing.

Comment: I just decompiled their Telerik.Sitefinity.dll and found how it works