# Sitefinity Password Hash in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, hash, sitefinity

I'm working on a project that requires using a client's existing Sitefinity database for user logins. I'm only able to build in PHP, and am trying to hash the passwords in PHP, and compare them with the hashed passwords in the Sitefinity database.

I'm came across, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423345/telerik-sitefinity-password-hash-function), which explains how Sitefinity does it's hashing, and it was a help to get started, but I don't fully understand it as it's obviously written in ASP. I need to find if there's a PHP equivalent and how that would work.

I've searched online for some guidance but no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP code for checking Sitefinity hash will looks like:

```
<?php
    //clear password
    $passwordInput = "password";

    //from sf_users column [salt]
    $userSalt = "2E1C1CEF99E6EF066E9C803974D17419";

    //from sf_users column [passwd]
    $userPassword = "G1MJiJw3zpBVdZBKViZUfEvTpZA=";

    //from App_Data\Sitefinity\Configuration\SecurityConfig.config attribute "validationKey"
    $validationKey = "24152EC6E594970CBEA98B5C10D878D65EF73964AAF44F1CCD3E0FBE95A5F2EFC89C0124B9B025581D38ED6EC846453249FD998ABDAE9453302B8BAB97BA1D0C";

    $str = $passwordInput.$userSalt;

    $utfString  = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-16LE");

    echo $userPassword == base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $utfString, hex2bin($validationKey), true))? 'true' : 'false';

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Unfortunately I'm not getting match between this function outputs and what Sitefinity has generated in it's database. Would you know if there could be any other variables that could be causing the difference?

Comment: I checked it on my Sitefinity instance, an hashes was equal

Comment: I'll make sure the validation key etc. is correct and try again. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So after rechecking a few values, this code does work.